# Step In / Debug ServicedComponent

Tags: com+, servicedcomponent

I have ServicedComponent that I have added it as a Reference (debug mode) in my test code, it has the pdb file in the same folder as the dll.

I am using VS 2010. I have checked Enable unmanaged code debugging, and Enable the Visual Studio Hosting process in both project Setttings. Both projects are local.

```
using(Gatherer nag = new Gatherer())
{
try
{
   nag.test(); ==> it won't step in test function.
```

I am able to However, when I try to step in, it will not step in. It will jump to the next line.

What else do I need to do to debug this ServicedComponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out. I have to select "Attach to Process", and select "dllhost.exe" from the list.